# Missing Project Templates in Visual Studio (after reinstall)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation

I uninstalled VS2008 Pro and installed VS2008 Team Suite.
Now I missing all the Windows Project types.
Console, WinForm, and WPF.
These projects are missing for C# and VB.NET.
I choose Full install.

I still have templates for Silverlight and MBUnit (I assume from Silverlight SDK and Gallio installs)

Before I do a simple uninstall / reinstall. Which I have the feeling won't work. How do I get a complete clean install of VS2008 Team Suite (hopefully minus starting over with new install of Windows)

Comment: get back to us after you've done an uninstall / reinstall

Comment: Ok. I'm trying again. This time uninstall / reinstall of Team Suite.

Answer (score 0):

So I uninstalled / reinstalled Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite. No change.

Then I stumbled upon this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fyc0azh.aspx
it mentioned the "run devenv.exe with the /installvstemplates switch"
nice to know about this. worked great!

Comment: I have the same problem and I read the MSDN article only problem is I don't have this devenv.exe on my DVD.  I am using Professional 2008...Wish they just had a link to download the templates.